# How can I speed up my array search function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, search, expo

I am working on dictionary application written with react-native.

When I want to filter the array from the search box, I wrote below function. This is working quite good when I test with 2000 word list. But when the word list goes to thousands the search speed is really slow.

So, how can I improve this search function?

```
//Filter array when input text (Search)

let filteredWords = []
if(this.state.searchField != null)
{
  filteredWords = this.state.glossaries.filter(glossary => {
    return glossary.word.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase());
  })
}
```

Comment: This kind of questions is suited for CodeReview not StackOverflow. Try posting it there.

Comment: ... Also `Array` functions such as `filter` are quite slow in comparaison with regular `for` loops. If you are trying to make your code faster, then refactor it using a `for` loop which won't be hard to do.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The question as is lacks a lot of context and would be off-topic in its current form on Code Review. See *[A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)* for more information.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I don't agree. Maybe the question could have been worded better, but this is not about making suggestions on how to improve code quality. This question is about a problem: Bad performance.

Comment: It will be hard to answer this question without a description of `glossary.word` or `glossary` in general. That being said, binary search instead of `includes` should yield logarithmic time instead of linear one as long as your dictionary is sorted.

Comment: Binary search wouldn't work though, seeing as `includes` matches more than only the start of the string.

Comment: Whoops. Misread `includes()` as the `Array.prototype.includes` variant.

Comment: A zero-cost solution could be create an index using the first letter of each word. E.g. filteredWords['a'] = []; filteredWords['b'] = []; filteredWords['c'] = [];
so you can apply your search into an array smaller than the original.
Of course this is not scalable, but I guess also that your glossary can have a defined upper bound of growth.

Comment: @user3036876 Is it a requirement that the user can search in the middle of words? It can be significantly sped up if that user can only search from the start of words.

Comment: This function is basically searching for middle letter. However, performance would be better if searching from the start of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question [**doesn't**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49963837/how-can-i-speed-up-my-array-search-function#comment86943832_49963837) seem to belong on CodeReview, I think there are a few things that you can do to make your code drastically faster [citation needed]:

- Cache that call to `this.state.searchField.toLowerCase()` as you don't need to call it on every iteration.
- Use regular old `for` loops instead of flashy-but-slow `Array` functions.

And here is the final result:

```
let filteredWords = []
if(this.state.searchField != null) {
    let searchField = this.state.searchField.toLowerCase(),
        theArray = this.state.glossaries;                          // cache this too

    for(let i = 0, l = theArray.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if(theArray[i].word.toLowerCase().includes(searchField)) {
            filteredWords.push(theArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to search for glossaries whose `word` start with `searchField`, then use `indexOf === 0` instead of `includes` as the condition like this:

```
if(theArray[i].word.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchField) === 0) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much guy. Your code is too fast than what I wrote.

One more thing, I found that. This searching is "searchField = 'he'". It will select "{ahello, ahellob, hello, aahello, hellob, helloc}"

But I think it would be faster if the searching algorithm is "{searchField = 'he'}". It should give result only "{he, hell, hello, hellob, helloc}"

could you give me some idea to write this searching.

Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: What I found is like this
Searching word 'A'
Result 'Aa, ab, ac, abbb, aee.' Not Result 'bAa, Aa, ab, Bac,.----'

Comment: @user3036876 Check the **Edit**!

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple factors that are making this code slow:

- You're using `filter()` with a lambda. This adds a function call overhead for each item being searched.
- You're calling `toLowercase()` on both strings before calling `includes()`. This will allocate two new string objects for every comparison.
- You're calling `includes`. For some reason the `includes()` method is not as well optimized in some browsers as `indexOf()`.

#### `for` loop (-11%)

Instead of using the `filter()` method, I recommend creating a new `Array` and using a `for` loop to fill it.

```
const glossaries = this.state.glossaries;
const searchField = this.state.searchField;
const filteredWords = [];   

for (let i = 0; i < glossaries.length; i++) {
  if (glossaries[i].toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())) {
    filteredWords.push(glossaries[i]);
  }
}
```

#### toLowerCase allocations (-45%)

Memory allocation is expensive due to the fact that JavaScript uses garbage collection mechanism for freeing used memory. When a garbage collection is performed the whole program is paused while it tries to finds memory which is not used anymore.

You can get rid of the `toLowerCase()` (inside the search loop) completely by making a copy of the glossary everytime the glossary is updated, which I assume is not often.

```
// When you build the glossary
this.state.glossaries = ...;
this.state.searchGlossaries = this.state.glossaries.map(g => g.toLowerCase());
```

You can also remove the `toLowerCase()` on the searchText by calling it once before the loop. After these changes, the code will look like:

```
const glossaries = this.state.glossaries;
const searchGlassaries = this.state.searchGlossaries;
const searchField = this.state.searchField.toLowerCase();
const filteredWords = []; 

for (let i = 0; i < glossaries.length; i++) {
  if (searchGlassaries[i].includes(searchField)) {
    filteredWords.push(glossaries[i]);
  }
}
```

#### `indexOf()` instead of `includes()` (-13%)

I am not really sure why this is the case, but tests show that `indexOf` is a lot faster than `includes`.

```
const glossaries = this.state.glossaries;
const searchGlassaries = this.state.searchGlossaries;
const searchField = this.state.searchField.toLowerCase();
const filteredWords = []; 

for (let i = 0; i < glossaries.length; i++) {
  if (searchGlassaries[i].indexOf(searchField) !== -1) {
    filteredWords.push(glossaries[i]);
  }
}
```

Overall the performance has improved by 70%.
I got the performance percentages from https://jsperf.com/so-question-perf

## Optimize the algorithm

In the comments you said you would like an example of optimizations that can be done when the requirements are loosened to only match words that start with the search text. One way to do this is a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Let's take the code from above as starting point. We sort the glossaries before we store it in the state. For sorting case insensitively, JavaScript exposes the [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) constructor. It provides the `compare(x, y)` method that returns:

```
negative value  | X is less than Y
zero            | X is equal to Y
positive value  | X is greater than Y
```

And the resulting code:

```
// Static in the file
const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
  sensitivity: 'base'
});

function binarySearch(glossaries, searchText) {
  let lo = 0;
  let hi = glossaries.length - 1;

  while (lo <= hi) {
    let mid = (lo + hi) / 2 | 0;
    let comparison = collator.compare(glossaries[mid].word, searchText);

    if (comparison < 0) {
      lo = mid + 1;
    }
    else if (comparison > 0) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    }
    else {
      return mid;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

// When you build the glossary
this.state.glossaries = ...;
this.state.glossaries.sort(function(x, y) {
  return collator.compare(x.word, y.word);
});

// When you search
const glossaries = this.state.glossaries;
const searchField = this.state.searchField.toLowerCase();
const filteredWords = [];

const idx = binarySearch(glossaries, searchField);

if (idx != -1) {
  // Find the index of the first matching word, seeing as the binary search
  // will end up somewhere in the middle
  while (idx >= 0 && collator.compare(glossaries[idx].word, searchField) < 0) {
    idx--;
  }

  // Add each matching word to the filteredWords
  while (idx < glossaries.length && collator.compare(glossaries[idx].word, searchField) == 0) {
    filteredWords.push(glossaries[idx]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much guy. Your code is too fast than what I wrote. One more thing, I found that. This searching is "searchField = 'he'". It will select "{ahello, ahellob, hello, aahello, hellob, helloc}" But I think it would be faster if the searching algorithm is "{searchField = 'he'}". It should give result only "{he, hell, hello, hellob, helloc}" could you give me some idea to write this searching. Thank you again for helping me

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you a lot for your help. By the way, could you explain me the below code?

// Static in the file
const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
  sensitivity: 'base'
});


// When you build the glossary
this.state.glossaries = ...;
this.state.glossaries.sort(function(x, y) {
  return collator.compare(x.word, y.word);
});

Comment: @user3036876 The "Static in the file" code goes outside the class declaration (assuming you're using React). The "When you build the glossary" goes at the location where `this.state.glossaries` gets set.